# Run a Process silently in background without any window

Tags: c#, process, netsh

I want to run NETSH command silently (with no window). 
I wrote this code but it does not work.

```
public static bool ExecuteApplication(string Address, string workingDir, string arguments, bool showWindow)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = Address;
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = showWindow;
    return proc.Start();
}

string cmd= "interface set interface name=\"" + InterfaceName+"\" admin=enable";
ExecuteApplication("netsh.exe","",cmd, false);
```

Comment: Well you're passing in `false` for `CreateNoWindow`... so you've *asked* it to create a window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I do it in a project of mine:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();            
psi.FileName = "netsh";            
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.Arguments = "SOME_ARGUMENTS";

Process proc = Process.Start(psi);                
proc.WaitForExit();
string errorOutput = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string standardOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if (proc.ExitCode != 0)
    throw new Exception("netsh exit code: " + proc.ExitCode.ToString() + " " + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput) ? " " + errorOutput : "") + " " + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(standardOutput) ? " " + standardOutput : ""));
```

It also accounts for the outputs of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Make user shell execution `false`

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

and pass true in `showWindow` parameter

```
ExecuteApplication("netsh.exe","",cmd, true);
```

Comment: It would also be helpful to change the behaviour inside `ExecuteApplication`. The `showWindow` parameter currently does the exact opposite of what it's name indicates.